# Custom UVgenerator Three.js for extrudedgeometry

Tags: three.js, geometry, uv-mapping

I want to use a texture on the surface of my extruded geometry. I have been researching custom UVgenerators for a while now, and have found these related questions:
1.) [How to apply a texture to THREE.ExtrudeGeometry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797407/how-to-apply-a-texture-to-three-extrudegeometry/22867384#22867384)
2.) [Loaded texture appears blurred, or like a single color. How to make the texture crisp and sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864338/loaded-texture-appears-blurred-or-like-a-single-color-how-to-make-the-texture/23864709#23864709)

However, the method proposed to divide my geometry points by 1000 and to `mesh.scale.set(1000,1000,1)` doesn't work because my geometry is no longer in the correct place. I would prefer to specify the UV Mapping. One answer says to implement a custom uvgenerator based on the source code, but I am stuck & can't figure out what to do.

This is my geometry creation, the material is 512x512px, how can I map a texture onto the top?:

```
pointList=[[0,0,0],
        [0,1000,0],
        [750,1000,0],
        [750,750,0],
        [1000,750,0],
        [1000,0,0]]

for (i=0;i < pointList.length; i++) {

        point = pointList[i];

        x = point[0];
        y = point[1];

        myPoints.push( new THREE.Vector2 (x,y) );
    }

    myShape = new THREE.Shape( myPoints );
    extrusionSettings = {
        amount:height
    };

    myGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( myShape, extrusionSettings );
    resultshape = new THREE.Mesh( myGeometry, material );
```

Comment: Instead of a custom UV generator or scaling the model, see if you can get the effect you want like so: `texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; `texture.repeat.set( 1 / 500, 1 / 500 ); `texture.offset.set( 0.1, 0.5 );`. Experiment with the values.

Comment: @WestLangley you should make a formal answer so it can be approved.

Comment: @amjoconn I didn't answer the question; I suggested an alternative approach. The question was how to write a custom `UVGenerator`.

Comment: @WestLangley fair enough, but you did solve the problem.

Comment: @amjoconn OK, you win. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify custom UVs for your `ExtrudeGeometry` by specifying your own `UVGenerator`, one of the properties of `extrusionSettings`.

To specify your custom UV generator, you can use as a template `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.WorldUVGenerator`, which can be found in `src/extras/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry.js`.

There is a simpler solution that may work for you, however.

Instead of a custom UV generator, you can take advantage of the `offset` and `repeat` properties of your texture. Use the following pattern:

```
texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( 1 / 500, 1 / 500 );
texture.offset.set( 0.1, 0.5 );
```

three.js r.68